# Some labels not being generated on map contours

Tags: qgis, labeling, maps

I'm trying to produce a map using the latest QGIS incarnation: 2.18.11
After importing the UK OS contour data for one 100km grid square, I crop it using two contiguous polygons (1km squares). Two of the contour lines become cut into two separate parts. When applying labelling to the contour lines layer, I find that only one part of the two part lines displays the labels (50m & 60m in the attached)[image: Contour screen]. The two parts of the two lines have the same ID. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: does checking the "label every part of multipart features" option under the Label Rendering tab help?